# How to pass certificate in ws-federation authentication

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, ws-federation

I have a question regarding WS-FEDERATION authentication. We have set it up like so

```
        services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
    {
        sharedOptions.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        sharedOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = WsFederationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
        .AddWsFederation(options =>
    {
        options.Wtrealm = Configuration["wsfed:realm"];
        options.MetadataAddress = Configuration["wsfed:metadata"];
    }).AddCookie();
```

But the problem is that the middlewere whose address is given MetadataAddress demands certificates for it to work. I have the certificate file, but where do I set it up?

Comment: What algorithm does the middleware use?  IS the certificate for TLS or is the certificate for Authentication?

Comment: @jdweng It is a certificate for authentication

Comment: It is TLS for HTTPS.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/certauth?view=aspnetcore-6.0